# Unable to find MOD11A1/A2 data for Pakistan in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I need to analyze the LST products of MODIS, such as MOD11A1.061 and
MOD11A2.061, but I am unable to find any images for the KPK province of Pakistan for 2020 or even for 2021 or 2022. Why am I facing this problem. Any suggestions or alternatives?